# ElasticSearch join data within the same index

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am quite new with ElasticSearch and I am collecting some application logs within the same index which have this format

```
{
    "_index" : "app_logs",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "JVMYi20B0a2qSId4rt12",
    "_source" : {
      "username" : "mapred",
      "app_id" : "application_1569623930006_490200",
      "event_type" : "STARTED",
      "ts" : "2019-10-02T08:11:53Z"
}
```

I can have different event types. In this case I am interested in `STARTED` and `FINISHED`. I would like to query ES in order to get all the app that started in a certain day and enrich them with their end time. Basically I want to create couples of start/end (an end might also be missing, but that's fine).

I have realized join relations in sql cannot be used in ES and I was wondering if I can exploit some other feature in order to get this result in one query.

Edit: these are the details of the index mapping

```
{ 
 “app_logs" : {
  "mappings" : {
   "_doc" : {
    "properties" : {
      "event_type" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      “app_id" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "ts" : {
        "type" : "date"
      },
      “event_type” : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood is that you would want to collate list of documents having same `app_id` along with the `status` as either `STARTED` or `FINISHED`.

I do not think Elasticsearch is not meant to perform JOIN operations. I mean you can but then you have to design your documents as mentioned in this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html).

What you would need is an [Aggregation query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html).

Below is the sample mapping, documents, the aggregation query and the response as how it appears, which would actually help you get the desired result.

### Mapping:

```
PUT mystatusindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "username":{
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "app_id":{
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "event_type":{
        "type":"keyword"
      },
      "ts":{
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Documents

```
POST mystatusindex/_doc/1
{
    "username" : "mapred",
    "app_id" : "application_1569623930006_490200",
    "event_type" : "STARTED",
    "ts" : "2019-10-02T08:11:53Z"
}

POST mystatusindex/_doc/2
{
    "username" : "mapred",
    "app_id" : "application_1569623930006_490200",
    "event_type" : "FINISHED",
    "ts" : "2019-10-02T08:12:53Z"
}

POST mystatusindex/_doc/3
{
    "username" : "mapred",
    "app_id" : "application_1569623930006_490201",
    "event_type" : "STARTED",
    "ts" : "2019-10-02T09:30:53Z"
}

POST mystatusindex/_doc/4
{
    "username" : "mapred",
    "app_id" : "application_1569623930006_490202",
    "event_type" : "STARTED",
    "ts" : "2019-10-02T09:45:53Z"
}

POST mystatusindex/_doc/5
{
    "username" : "mapred",
    "app_id" : "application_1569623930006_490202",
    "event_type" : "FINISHED",
    "ts" : "2019-10-02T09:45:53Z"
}

POST mystatusindex/_doc/6
{
  "username" : "mapred",
  "app_id" : "application_1569623930006_490203",
  "event_type" : "STARTED",
  "ts" : "2019-10-03T09:30:53Z"
}

POST mystatusindex/_doc/7
{
  "username" : "mapred",
  "app_id" : "application_1569623930006_490203",
  "event_type" : "FINISHED",
  "ts" : "2019-10-03T09:45:53Z"
}
```

### Query:

```
POST mystatusindex/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "ts": {
              "gte": "2019-10-02T00:00:00Z",
              "lte": "2019-10-02T23:59:59Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "event_type": "STARTED"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "event_type": "FINISHED"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "application_IDs": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "app_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "ids": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10,
            "_source": ["event_type", "app_id"],
            "sort": [
              { "event_type": { "order": "desc"}}
              ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that for filtering I've made use of [Range Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) as you only want to filter documents for that date and also added a bool `should` logic to filter based on `STARTED` and `FINISHED`.

Once I have the documents, I've made use of [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) and [Top Hits Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) to get the desired result.

### Result

```
{
  "took" : 12,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 5,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "application_IDs" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "application_1569623930006_490200",       <----- APP ID
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "ids" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 2,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : null,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "mystatusindex",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "1",                     <--- Document with STARTED status
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "event_type" : "STARTED",     
                    "app_id" : "application_1569623930006_490200"
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    "STARTED"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "_index" : "mystatusindex",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "2",                    <--- Document with FINISHED status
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "event_type" : "FINISHED",     
                    "app_id" : "application_1569623930006_490200"
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    "FINISHED"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "application_1569623930006_490202",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "ids" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 2,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : null,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "mystatusindex",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "4",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "event_type" : "STARTED",
                    "app_id" : "application_1569623930006_490202"
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    "STARTED"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "_index" : "mystatusindex",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "5",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "event_type" : "FINISHED",
                    "app_id" : "application_1569623930006_490202"
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    "FINISHED"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "application_1569623930006_490201",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "ids" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 1,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : null,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "mystatusindex",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "3",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "event_type" : "STARTED",
                    "app_id" : "application_1569623930006_490201"
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    "STARTED"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the last document with only `STARTED` appears in the aggregation result as well.

### Updated Answer

```
{ 
   "size":0,
   "query":{ 
      "bool":{ 
         "must":[ 
            { 
               "range":{ 
                  "ts":{ 
                     "gte":"2019-10-02T00:00:00Z",
                     "lte":"2019-10-02T23:59:59Z"
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "should":[ 
            { 
               "term":{ 
                  "event_type.keyword":"STARTED"   <----- Changed this 
               }
            },
            { 
               "term":{ 
                  "event_type.keyword":"FINISHED"  <----- Changed this 
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs":{ 
      "application_IDs":{ 
         "terms":{ 
            "field":"app_id.keyword"               <----- Changed this 
         },
         "aggs":{ 
            "ids":{ 
               "top_hits":{ 
                  "size":10,
                  "_source":[ 
                     "event_type",
                     "app_id"
                  ],
                  "sort":[ 
                     { 
                        "event_type.keyword":{    <----- Changed this 
                           "order":"desc"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Note the changes I've made. Whenever you would need exact matches or want to make use of aggregation, you would need to make use of `keyword` type.

In the mapping you've shared, ***there is no `username` field but two `event_type` fields***. I'm assuming its just a human err and that one of the field should be `username`.

Now if you notice carefully, the field `event_type` has a `text` and its sibling `keyword` field. I've just modified the query to make use of the keyword field and when I am doing that, I'm use [Term Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html).

Try this out and let me know if it helps!

Comment: Thanks. It really looks like what I am looking for. I am going to give it a try. However can you clarify the mapping part? As far as I understood I should add a mapping of that kind to the index, but will it work for documents that are already there? Or should I restore them again?

Comment: I don't think you need to change mapping details if it mirrors to what I've answered. But I would like to know your index's mapping details.

Comment: @alexlipa By default if you do not specify the mapping while creating your index, ES would go ahead and depending on the data you send to it, it would go ahead and create a mapping. You can execute the below and share me the mapping details `GET <your_index_name>/_mapping` so I can take a look at it and let you know whether you need to do any changes or just change the query.

Comment: I have added my mappings detail

Comment: hey @alexlipa could you check the updated answer I've posted in section of the same. Let me know if that helps!